# How to write back to the CSV file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to write back to CSV file , How can I change this script to write back to CSV file,I am new to C#? Please help me

```
public void Main()
{

    List<String> lines = new List<string>();
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\NewFolder\\Test.csv");

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        lines.Add(line);
    }

    lines.RemoveAll(l => l.Contains(",,,,,"));

    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\NewFolder\\Test.csv", false))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(lines[i]);
        }
    }


    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902346/writing-in-an-csv-file-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Simply this

```
//Convert your list to csv string
string toWrite = string.Join(",",lines );
File.WriteAllText(YourFilePath, toWrite);
```

Comment: I am removing lines , but how can I tell it to CSV  ?

Comment: @Ehsan: I think you mean string.Join("", lines), otherwise you will get an extra comma at the start of each line (since ReadLine will return the line including the newline).

Comment: Wouldn't you want to join with with `Environment.NewLine` instead of comma or nothing?

Comment: Both of you are right but purpose is just to give an idea. He is formatting himself.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `StreamReader` to read from the file. Use a `StreamWriter` to write back to it. This code should do it

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt", false))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

Note this assumes 2 things:

1. You've closed your reader
2. You're wanting to replace the original file

EDIT: Alternatively you can rewrite the whole thing as:

```
string fileName = "C:\\NewFolder\\Test.csv";
List<string> lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
lines.RemoveAll(l => l.Contains(",,,,,"));
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines.ToArray());
```

Comment: I just tired but its throws me this error "Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\NewFolder\Test.csv' because it is being used by another process." I just updated my code ?

Comment: You've still got the file open reading it. See my note at the bottom of my answer. You need to call `file.Close();` or you need to point the writer to a new file. Alternatively you can enclose your reader in a `using` block like I have with the `StreamWriter`